# Load cell without In-amp

Tags: transistors, amplifier, instrumentation-amplifier, load-cell

I have a 0-1kg load cell with 4 wires: Excitation + and -, and Signal + and -. I haven't had any problems wiring them up correctly without amplification, and my voltmeter shows me a **1 mV** difference between no load and full load (1 kg).

The signal has to feed into an ATmega microcontroller, so ideally I would like to be able to use the full 10-bit analogue scale when reading the values (voltages from 0 to 5 V). In any case, as it stands now, I only get 1 / 1024 as a reading under full load.

I have a prototype deadline for a product soon, and silly as I am I don't have any instrumentation amps left. I tried wiring the signal wires to a general-purpose NPN transistor, but I'm not getting any amplification. This is the transistor configuration that I tried: ignore the double cell symbol for voltage, I couldn't find anything better.

[image: Transistor amp circuit]

I also tried adding resistors between drain and ground, but that didn't help.

Is there any way I could obtain a usable reading using components I have right now? Ordering a proper In-amp would take too long, and I don't really know what kind of op-amp would be suited for this kind of measurement (although that might be an option).

I don't have a big selection of stuff available, mainly different kinds of transistors. And of course diodes, capacitors, resistors, and the like.

Comment: There are transistor amplifier circuits.  (But that is not one of them.)  How about an opamp?  (got any of those?)  I assume the load cell has a low impedance so any type opamp should be better than what you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will never be able to get accurate amplification of a 1mV full scale DC signal with a simple circuit using discrete components (I do know a way, but it's not simple). Even a crappy LM324 will do better (because the transistors are matched and on one chip).

Tell us what you have and we can, perhaps, help. An [instrumentation amplifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumentation_amplifier) can be made with three op-amps, and as I said, even a crappy 10-cent LM324 will be better than trying to use discretes.

[image]

In general, an LM324 will probably drift about 5-10uV/K so you can expect (at best) errors commensurate with that- about 5g ~ 10g/°C. A better amplifier would reduce those errors.

By comparison an B-E junction (as in your voltage follower) changes -2mV/K so you'd see 2kg/°C change- worse than useless.

Comment: Thanks. I might be able to get access to op-amps, and price isn't a big issue (I'm not paying for it myself). So would any op-amp work, or is there a category/part better suited for my needs than others?

Comment: Precision op-amp, low offset voltage and low offset voltage drift. A low-noise 'zero drift' op-amp would be ideal.

Comment: You can request a sample of an instrumentation amp on TI's website and generally receive it within a day or so.  It might be an idea to do that in parallel with trying to get your op-amp circuit working.  Spehro is absolutely correct about trying to use discretes vs. even the worst op-amp.  It can be done (Philbrick!) but it will take you way longer to get it right than it would to just get the right components.